Does the Consumer Protection Act, S.O. 2002 apply only to purchases over $50?

Provincial legislation protects consumers in their specific dealings with vendors. The Ontario Consumer Protection Act, 2002, provides a general system of rights to consumers, who are defined as those who are purchasing goods or services for personal, family, or household purposes.
Generally, the Act applies to purchases over $50 in value, when either the consumer or the seller was located in Ontario at the time of purchase.


This column is brought to you by Community Law School (Sarnia-Lambton) Inc., and Community Legal Services and Pro Bono Students Canada at Western University, with funding support from the Law Foundation of Ontario.

Is this website dated "Jun 28, 2012" outdated"? I see no such $50 minimum purchase requirement in the Consumer Protection Act, 2002, S.O. 2002, c. 30, Sched. A as at January 1 2024.

Many sections of the Act only apply when the potential payment obligation exceeds a prescribed amount.

21 (1) Sections 22 to 26 apply to future performance agreements if the consumer’s total potential payment obligation under the agreement, excluding the cost of borrowing, exceeds a prescribed amount.
...
29 (1) Sections 30 to 36 apply in respect of personal development services or proposed personal development services for which ... the consumer’s total potential payment obligation, excluding cost of borrowing, exceeds a prescribed amount.
...
37 Sections 38 to 40 apply to an internet agreement if the consumer’s total potential payment obligation under the agreement, excluding the cost of borrowing, exceeds a prescribed amount.
...
41 (1) Sections 42 and 43 apply to direct agreements if the consumer’s total potential payment obligations under the agreement, excluding the cost of borrowing, exceeds a prescribed amount.
...
44 Sections 45 to 47 apply to remote agreements if the consumer’s total potential payment obligation under the agreement, excluding the cost of borrowing, exceeds a prescribed amount.

The prescribed amount for each of those sections is set to $50 by Ontario Regulation 17/05.

23.1 The prescribed amount for the purpose of subsection 21 (1) of the Act is $50 if the future performance agreement mentioned in that subsection is not a gift card agreement to which sections 25.2 to 25.5 apply.
...
27. The prescribed amount for the purpose of clause 29 (1) (b) of the Act is $50.
...
31. The prescribed amount for the purpose of section 37 of the Act is $50.
...
34. The prescribed amount for the purpose of subsection 41 (1) of the Act is $50.
...
36. The prescribed amount for the purpose of section 44 of the Act is $50.

